# Can I write $(12)(34)$ as one cycle?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have trouble understanding an exercise. I wanted to know if I can write a cycle like $(12)(34)$ as one cycle instead of a multiplication?

Comment: No, this is the simplest form since there are no elements that are the same in the two 2-cycles.

Comment: With one cycle, I do not mean a cycle of length 1. I just wanted to know if I can write this as one cycle instead of a multiplication of two cycles. Does that change your answer?

Comment: Ah ok then my second comment is not relevant. The first still holds.

Answer (score 3):

No: the decomposition as a product of disjoint cycles is unique, up to the order.

For this one particularly, such a cycle would involve $1,2,3$ and $4$, hence it would be cycle of length  $\ell\ge 4$, and its order  would be $\ell-1\ge 3$, whereas $(12)(34)$ has order $2$.

Comment: Why  the second sentence? Just knowing the decomposition as a product of disjoint cycles is unique already says no, a product of two disjoint cycles is not equal to a cycle....

Comment: In case the O.P. doesn't have seen the decomposition theorem yet, it yields a direct proof.